# IOUtils issue for 'cat' of data from HDFS in Java program

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm learning Hadoop, and after having successfully executed the basic WordCount example, I'm now interested in defining my own job.

At the moment I'm trying to simply `cat` data that I've uploaded to HDFS on the terminal, I've consulted many tutorials- but the majority of my code is based off [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COGeG5Hj79o).

Here's what I've come up with:

```
/******************
 *
 *  core-site.xml
 *
 *  <configuration>
 *    <property>
 *       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 *       <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
 *    </property>
 *  </configuration>
 *
 *********************/ 
// InputStream()
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
// Configuration()
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
// FileSystem is not public in java.io
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;  
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;

public class FileSystemCat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://master:9000");

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        InputStream in = null;

        try{

            in = fs.open(new Path("/input_1/codes.txt"));

            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);

        }finally{
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm executing it on the NameNode with this command:

```
javac -cp /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/job_program/commons-io-2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar FileSystemCat.java
```

Since I'm using `IOUtils` I know that I need to include the path to the `commons` lib on my classpath, and as it's a Hadoop program, also those `jar`s, but I'm not fully convinced that this execution command is correct.

The console spits out the following error:

[image]

That is:

```
FileSystemCat.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
               ^
  symbol:   method copyBytes(InputStream,PrintStream,int,boolean)
  location: class IOUtils
FileSystemCat.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable in
  location: class FileSystemCat
2 errors
```

Is there a different utility than `IOUtils` that I should use to output the data? Is there something else wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you still getting the "cannot find symbol" error on `in`?  If not, you should update the error text/graphic in your question.

Comment: Regarding the `copyBytes()` error, I don't see anything wrong with your code.  It looks quite similar to [this tutorial code](http://hadooptutorial.info/java-interface-to-hdfs-file-read-write/).  Perhaps you're missing the jar file where IOUtils is defined?  I'm not familiar enough with the hadoop environment to say anything definite regarding the classpath in your situation.

Comment: @azurefrog is there something wrong with my execution command?

Comment: I couldn't say.  It's been years since I've used hadoop, and I just don't remember enough about it.

Comment: man- I think this is whats causing my problems